# Wrap existing SVG elements using the svg.js library

Tags: javascript, svg, svg.js

How can I wrap existing `<svg>` element in `svg.js`?

For example:

```
<svg>
    <circle r="10" cx="10" cy="10" fill="red"></circle>
</svg>
```

I know this can be built with svg.js very easy, but I take it as example for my question.

```
var existingSvg = Svg.<some-method>(document.querySelector("svg"));
existingSvg.children(); // circle
```

How can I do this?

I tried using `SVG('<id-ofsvg-element>')`, but `children()` returns an empty array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question with a new answer: 
In v2 svg.js can pickup other instances of svg by simply calling `SVG.get('id')` which then will return the instance for this svg

// EDIT: to make sure, that all methods work properly you should call `SVG.prepare(element)` when you dont have another SVG in your document already. I think thats a bug which should be fixed

// EDIT2: It should even be possible to use SVG('id') to get the root instance already. This would make the call to SVG.prepare() obsolete, too

Comment: That should be amazing. Thanks!

Comment: What if I have the actual element, rather than an id?

Comment: You would use the adopt method

Answer (score 2):

There is a [plugin called svg.absorb.js](https://github.com/wout/svg.absorb.js) which lets you import existing SVGs. To use it, execute

```
draw.absorb(element)
```

Comment: It possible to load it in place as well? This just copies the existing svg into a `SVG` instance.